# How to read CSV and store it nested Map

Tags: java

I am trying to create a simple currency exchange program that reads from CSV file and exchange from one currency to another

these are data from my CSV file

```
Symbol, Currency, Dollar
USD,US Dollar,1
EUR,Euro,0.842850125
GBP,British Pound,0.761549464
INR,Indian Rupee,63.72054347
AUD,Australian Dollar,1.259237335
CAD,Canadian Dollar,1.257801755
.......
```

Here is my code

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/forex.csv"));
    String line = null;
    Map<String,Map<String, String>> outer = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> inner1 = new HashMap<>();

    while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
        String str[] = line.split(",");
        inner1.put(str[1],str[2]);
        outer.put(str[0],inner1);
    }

    System.out.println(outer);
```

Desired output like this

```
'USD': {'Currency': 'US Dollar', 'Dollar': '1'}, 'EUR': {'Currency': 'Euro', 'Dollar': '0.842850125'},
```

But I am now getting weird data which is way too long. I guess for each currency it's storing all the data from all the currencies and it is looping with no end.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can not re-use `inner1` because you will fill the same map over and over again. Also you're not putting the correct values into `inner` compared to your desired output:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String str[] = line.split(",");

    String currencyCode = str[0];

    Map<String, String> inner = new HashMap<>();

    String currency = str[1];
    inner.put('Currency', currency);

    String xChangeRate = str[2];
    inner.put('Dollar', xChangeRate);

    outer.put(currencyCode, inner);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You put the same `HashMap` `inner1`  into all `outer`-Nodes. You could create a separate map for each entry like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/forex.csv"));
String line = null;
Map<String,Map<String, String>> outer = new HashMap<>();

while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
    String str[] = line.split(",");
    Map<String, String> inner1 = new HashMap<>();
    inner1.put(str[1],str[2]);
    outer.put(str[0],inner1);
}

System.out.println(outer);
```